# Add two maps in Groovy while summing up values for common keys

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I have two maps in Groovy `[a: 1, b: 2]` and `[b:1, c:3]` and would like to create from them a third map `[a: 1, b: 3, c: 3]`. Is there a Groovy command that does that?

**Edit**: Notice that the values in the third map, are a sum of the values from the first two maps, if the keys are identical.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yet another solution would be:

```
def m1 = [ a:1, b:2 ]
def m2 = [ b:1, c:3 ]

def newMap = [m1,m2]*.keySet().flatten().unique().collectEntries {
  [ (it): [m1,m2]*.get( it ).findAll().sum() ]
}
```

Taking [epidemian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10131141/6509) as inspiriation, you can also write a method to handle multiple maps

```
def m1 = [a: 1, b: 2]
def m2 = [b: 1, c: 3]

def combine( Map... m ) {
  m.collectMany { it.entrySet() }.inject( [:] ) { result, e ->
    result << [ (e.key):e.value + ( result[ e.key ] ?: 0 ) ]
  }
}

def newMap = combine( m1, m2 )
```

Comment: I think providing a complete method with a nice signature like your second example (instead of the expression thrown in the air) really adds a little bit to the overall quality of the response, because it's how we should write these kind of things in "real" code if we worry about code quality. +1 =D

Answer (score 13):

This should work for any number of maps:

```
def maps = [[a: 1, b: 2], [b:1, c:3]]

def result = [:].withDefault{0}
maps.collectMany{ it.entrySet() }.each{ result[it.key] += it.value }

assert result == [a: 1, b: 3, c: 3]
```

The `maps.collectMany{ it.entrySet() }` expression returns a list of map entries, like `[a=1, b=2, b=1, c=3]`, and then each of those is added to the result.

Another option, if you'd like to keep all the transformation into one expression and make it "more functional", is to first group the entries by key and then sum the values, but I think it's less readable:

```
def result = maps.collectMany{ it.entrySet() }
    .groupBy{ it.key }
    .collectEntries{[it.key, it.value.sum{ it.value }]}
```

The `groupBy` part returns a map of the form `[a:[a=1], b:[b=2, b=1], c:[c=3]]` and then the `collectEntries` transforms that map into another one that has the same kays but has the sum of the lists in the values instead.

Comment: +1 nice use of `collectMany` (inspired me to write a vararg method)

Comment: Cool! I like how that "combine" method looks. This is totally off-topic and irrelevant but, isn't it weird that when writing chained calls like `foo.bar { ... }.baz { ... }` there should be a space between the method name and the opening curly brace of the closure but not between the closing curly brace and the next dot operator? I thought it looked weird when writing my answer, so I removed the first space, but it doesn't look too good either...

Comment: Yeah, it's because parentheses are optional if the last parameter of a method is a closure... hard to get it looking nice sometimes ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The following example demonstrates adding two maps, to a third map `m3`:

```
Map m1 = [ a:1, b:2 ];
Map m2 = [ b:1, c:3 ];
Map m3 = [:];
m3 << m1
m3 << m2
```

Comment: Seems like answered without reading the question. He wanted to add value from both maps if key is mapping. It does not answer the question

Comment: You can't blame him when the title is so confusing!

Answer (score 3):

A nice way is it use the spread operator:

```
def m1 = [ a:1, b:2 ]
def m2 = [ b:1, c:3 ]
def m3 = [ *:m1, *:m2 ]

println "m1 = $m1"
println "m2 = $m2"
println "m3 = $m3"
```

*Credit:http://mrhaki.blogspot.ch/2009/09/groovy-goodness-spread-operator.html

The code above does not work in groovysh but it is fine in the groovy console. (for version 1.8)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that he wanted to apply the sum in the values of the maps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a ready-made method for this, maybe use something like:

```
def m1 = [a: 1, b: 2]
def m2 = [b: 1, c: 3]
def newMap = (m1.keySet() + m2.keySet()).inject([:]) { 
    acc, k -> acc[k] = (m1[k] ?: 0) + (m2[k] ?: 0); acc 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
Map additionJoin( Map map1, Map map2 )
{
  def result = [:];
  result.putAll( map1 );
  result.putAll( map2 );

  result.each { key, value ->
    if( map1[key] && map2[key] )
    {
      result[key] = map1[key] + map2[key]
    }
  }

  return result;
}

def a = [a: 1, b: 2]
def b = [b:1,c:3]

def c = additionJoin( a, b )

println c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge(map1, map2) { 
    def add = { map, entry -> map << entry }
    map2.inject(map1.inject([:], add), add)
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Loosing the key `a`  and not adding values from both maps for key `b`